# Angular2 Reactive Form Model Binding - Multi Select not reflecting updates

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a pretty complex form that has been a pain thus far setting up. I am getting down to the end here and running into some trouble.

I am using a multi-select plugin called `ng-select`. This directive takes two arrays of data, `[items]` and `[active]`. Items being the list of possible options and active being the values selected by default.

I am trying to configure this with my reactive form model.

```
<span>
    <ng-select formControlName="AttributeValue" [allowClear]="true" [multiple]="true" [items]="fetchSourceList()" [active]="formatValues(ruleAttributeData.AttributeValue)" placeholder="Click to Select a Value" class="inlineSelect"></ng-select>
</span>
```

Here is an image of what my form looks like so far:

[image]

The `array` seen at the bottom is what my model contains when it creates the form. Those are the selected values.

The method used for populating the `active` (default selected) looks like this:

```
export interface ValueData {
    RuleDetailID?: number;
    AttrValue: string;
    Value: string;
    IsValueRetired: boolean;
}

private formatValues(data) {
    return data.map((data: ValueData) => {
        return { id: data.AttrValue, text: data.Value };
    });
}
```

My `fetchSourceList()` method just returns an array of possible items to select from. When invoking the dropdown to choose a new option, I don't see the options that are already selected, which is a good thing. It makes me thing that the model binding works initially but then breaks somewhere after,

So far, the page loads fine, my default selected items are marked as selected in the UI, and the value of the `form` shows the 8 items in the array as expected.

Here comes the issue..

Although my `[items]="fetchSourceList()"` contains the list of data thats not already selected, picking an option doesn't add it to the input.

When I select an input from the available options, the select input doesn't show it added. When I get the value of the form, I see that the item WAS added to the array of selected items, with a catch.. If I continue to select options from the list, its always the last one I selected that ends up as number 8 in my array.

Secondly, if I remove an item from this multi-select on the ui, it doesn't remove.

So, there appears to be some model issue here that is not working as expected.

Anything stand out that I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am not so sure about this , but Can you check if the method formatValues() is actually working ? , it is defined as a private method and you are trying to access it from DOM.

Comment: @priteshagrawal - It is working, just confirmed. `ruleAttributeData.AttributeValue` is an object that I pass through the interface in order to format it specifically for the multi select. The data needs to be formatted as an array of objects that have a `text` and `id` key. In this case, they would show up as `undefined` if the method wasnt working.

Comment: @priteshagrawal It does however seem to be calling that method multiple times, one per array value it seems.If my array contains 10 options to pick form, the `formatValues` method is getting called 10 times. Seems odd...

Comment: ok @SBS  , can you try doing it two way binding  ? .I have not used ng-select ever , but i and using some other UI libs wherein do something similar stuff , something like [(active)] = "formatValues(ruleAttributeData.AttributeValue)" and [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"

Comment: How would I do this when using a reactive form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://basvandenberg.github.io/ng-select/) (see Documentation link in that page), the `ng-select` doesn't seem to have `items` or `active` as its `Input` property. For specifying the list of options, you need to use `options` property. For choosing the `active` selections set it as the default value of the `formControl` within the component.

`allowClear` property is used only for single selects (not multi-selects).

Also, your options array elements should conform to this type as per the docs,

```
interface IOption {
    value: string;
    label: string;
    disabled?: boolean; // this is optional
}
```

You can import this interface as,

```
import { IOption } from 'ng-select';
```

Assuming, from your example, each of your `option` element consists of values like `{ id: "172", text: "Account Manager" }`, where `id` is the actual `value` to be stored and `text` is the `label` to be shown, we have to make the array for 'options' conform to the IOptions interface like this (omitting `disabled` property as it is 'optional'),

> component

```
import { IOption } from 'ng-select';

form: FormGroup;
// choose the 'active' or default selections for the options dropdown
// by including the corresponding 'value' property of IOptions list elements
// returned from the getOptions() call. Use it as the formControl's initial value (array since it is multi-select)
defaultSelections = ['172', '180', '113']; 

ngOnInit() {
 this.form = new FormGroup({
  AttributeValue: new FormControl(this.defaultSelections)
 });
}

getOptions(data): Array<IOption> {
    return data.map((data: ValueData) => {
        return { value: data.AttrValue, label: data.Value };
    });
}
```

> template

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="form">
 <span>
  <ng-select formControlName="AttributeValue" [multiple]="true" [options]="getOptions(ruleAttributeData.AttributeValue)" placeholder="Click to Select a Value" class="inlineSelect">
  </ng-select>
 </span>
</form>
```

I haven't tried this myself (never worked with `ng-select` before), but I'm pretty convinced from the docs and the examples given there that it will work. You might have to tweak the variables/methods used in the component to the way you want it to work for your particular use-case. Hope it helps.